# Colorful Puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

This puzzle is based on the squares before the one that says, "what color is this?".

This is a sequence of squares, try to follow the rule(s) for the puzzle.

Can you solve it?
[image: squares in a horizontal line: purple, blue, yellow, purple, orange, yellow, unknown]

Comment: Just to make sure, Is the first and fourth color violet? And the second blue?

Comment: yes, well kinda, the allowed colors are red orange yellow green blue purple

Comment: okay with that info, I revised my answer, is it closer?

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

Using the OP's new comment that there are 6 allowable colors "red orange yellow green blue purple", it is now possible to see a pattern.

> Those are the spectral colors, in that order.
>  So we have:
>  PURPLE (skip 5 - red orange yellow green BLUE)
>  BLUE (skip 4 - purple red orange YELLOW)
>  YELLOW (skip 3 - green blue PURPLE)
>  PURPLE (skip 2 - red ORANGE)
>  ORANGE (skip 1 - YELLOW)
>  YELLOW (skip 0 - YELLOW)

So the missing color is:

> YELLOW.

To be honest, I am not sure the puzzle was solvable without that extra comment. Red and green don't even appear in the puzzle so linking this to the primary colors seemed a stretch without the giveaway, nor was there enough data to jump to the conclusion that those colors were missing. Hence my original, completely serious but now clearly incorrect guess, that the answer was... light blue ; )

We'll see if this one is right now...

Comment: this is close and is one of the patterns I would have accepted but there was another one that followed a backward trend of purple then blue skip none then yellow skip one and so on, this was a cool answer and thank you for participating in this puzzle

Comment: I believe going backwards and incrementing is logically equivalent to going forwards and decrementing?  Or are you saying this answer is incorrect and I should give this more thought?

Answer (score 0):

> Not too confident, but I think based off of my picture, the pattern has something to do with colors being complementary to one another, as denoted by the arrow with a C above it. Based off that, I think the next color should be purple.

> [image]

Comment: Where is the color purple would be complementary with?

Comment: The new purple that I suggest is in the box? I think that it would be complementary with a yellow that would be present if this pattern/cycle continued.

Comment: close but not yet the colors are linked to each other though in some way, also Hint think about the colors of the rainbow. I will post the answer in a few days if no one get it.